# Reoccurring error message when trying to upload to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I try to upload my own created theme I get the error message:

> ```
> "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2013/11. Is its parent directory writable by the server?"
> ```

also when I try to upload images the error message is:

> ```
> "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2013/11. Is its parent directory writable by the server?"
> ```

any idea what I'm doing wrong? 
I'm uploading the theme straight from my desktop in a zipped folder. 
I know this theme works as I've uploaded it before without any problems but it was a long time ago so I'm obviously doing something different.
The image I tried to upload through the media area in the wordpress/wp-admin area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you got a permission issue. Because...

1. The theme is probably fine as that error comes out before installation.
2. As image files are also facing problem, so it is most likely permission issue.

You didn't specified your system, so I can generally conclude that, altering your root directory permission will work.

The codex has details on [changing permission of folder and files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions).

2 piece of advice as I faced these problems earlier:

1. Make sure to apply appropriate permissions to sub directories also.

   e.g. Sometimes one changes root permission only, but tries to upload stuff to /wp-content inside root with a different permission, and throws an error like you're getting.
2. If it is your localhost installation, then change the root and everything under it to permission 777. Otherwise be cautious as using 777 permission on a live website will make it vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: thanks i'll give it a go. it probably will be because when i last worked on it i was able to do it from the desktop (different server) this server ive got up upload to filezilla

Comment: can you change the permissions via user table in phpmyadmin? tried following codex but it didnt match up in the slightest so didnt get anywhere, bit stuck.. thank you

Comment: nevermind lol i figured it out. it was the permissions fixed it now :D